# Java - print a List<>

Tags: java, list, printing

Assuming I have a `List<Item>` and I want to print it so that it will be printed as `[ item print, item print, ...]`, but I don't know the dynamic type of the List. (There is an implementation for Item.toString() , print for example "item print").

Is there a way for me to easily print it?

I have tried to search for answers, but all of them seem to be of lists that we do know the dynamic type (such as ArrayList), where in my case I do not know. Also, java's oracle's documentation of Collection and List does not seem to have the toString() method mentioned.

Thanks!

Comment: The `toString()` method will work if the List is of type `AbstractCollection`, but not all Lists are, and not all lists override the `Object.toString()` method.

Comment: The important thing is to override toString in the Item class.  All implementations of the List interface will implement toString for the List.

Comment: @duffymo - Incorrect. Standard implementations may, but anyone can implement a List, and may not have defined `Object.toString()`.

Comment: I was thinking of the standard implementations.  You are correct - toString does not appear in the interface, so it's not mandated.

Comment: @duffymo - Even if it did appear in the interface, an override would still would not be mandated. An implementation is already provided by the Object class. With Java 8, a default implementation *could* be provided by the interface, but is not.

Comment: Correct again.  Thank you for the education, Andy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first go to your Item class, and @override the toString() method, after that, you can go through the list and print it:

```
System.out.print("[");
for(Item it : myListOfItems) {
     System.out.print(it.toString() + ", ");
}
System.out.print("]");
```

Comment: I understand from the other answers and comments that the only way to make sure the print is correct is by writing your code, so there is no "simple" way to implement it, since the given list may not have a toString method.
Am I correct? And wouldn't it be better to use an iterator?
(I have overrided the toString method for Item, as I wrote in the question).

Comment: @Mickey Is the same, you can use both :), I don't know why somebody downvoted my answer hahaha, if it works for you, I'm glad :)

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't sure if iterating and using that kind of for loop will return the same order. :)

Comment: @Mickey Yes of course it does! Don't worry sometimes is hard to notice that

Comment: This is what Arrylist or linkedlist are doing in toString through AbstractCollection. thanks Andy.

Comment: @PradeepSingh andy?

Comment: thanks Damian. Happy now ;)

Comment: @PradeepSingh hahahaah no problem, I thought you override my name to! oooh... bad joke sorry... ahahah

Answer (score 3):

Check this out

```
public class ABC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        Item e1 = new Item();
        Item e2 = new Item();
        items.add(e1);
        items.add(e2);
        System.out.println(items);
    }
}
class Item {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "item print";
    }
}
```

output

```
[item print, item print]
```

Comment: You have an ArrayList. The OP specifically states that he does not know the actual type of the List.

Comment: Actually output pattern will be same regardless of type of list. Because All list type (arraylist or linkedlist) returns  a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space).  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()

Comment: Not true. You're thinking of the List classes provided by the standard Java SDK. **But anyone can implement a List class, and not all such implementations implement `toString()`.**

Comment: @PradeepSingh, the answer it's ok IF you just asume you have an implementation of list, you don't know wich one, so you use the interface List, and asume the OP use an implementator of that class, and that's it. But besides, is not a wrong answer, you can modify it a little perhaps, you have a plus one for the aproach

Comment: @DamianLattenero - It's not enough that there's an implementation of `List`. We already know there's an implementation, or you couldn't make an instance. The assumption would be that the implementation overrides `toString()`, and that assumption can be wrong in some cases. Your answer avoids this assumption, and is the only one at this time that avoids it.

Comment: @AndyThomas That's correct, and that's is what I meant to say... maybe I expressed bad myself

Comment: :D haha Let's move to next java question guys. We have understood the question now.. ;)

Answer (score -3):

Any sensible `List` implementation (specifically `ArrayList`) implements `toString()` by calling all of of its items' `toString()` and joining them with some delimiter (usually a comma). To make a long story short - just let Java do its thing and call the default `toString()`:

```
System.out.println(myList);
```

Comment: There exist sensible List implementations that do not implement `toString()`. Anyone can implement a List. They might or might not have implemented `toString()`, depending on whether it's necessary for their requirements. The OP states specifically that he does not know the actual type of the List.